# How to get child node from Firebase database Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

How can I reference and store the value of this child node?

`GroupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups");`

I have attempted with `String groupAdmin = GroupRef.child("Admin").child("").toString();`

[image]

Comment: if the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of the node under `Admin`, then do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Groups").child("Baby Names");
ref.child("Admin").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             String key = ds.getValue(String.class);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
})
```

`String key = ds.getValue(String.class);` this will retrieve the circled key in your question. You need to know all the nodes before this child to be able to reach it, and then iterate and retrieve the value.